# Google functions firestore date

Tags: javascript, date, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to store data into firestore from functions but i have a problem with dates.
My function:

```
const newScheduleEventRef = db.collection('scheduleEvents').doc();  
batch.set(newScheduleEventRef, {
  user_id: context.auth.uid,  
  category: 1,
  startDate1: new Date(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0),  
  startDate2: new Date(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0),
  endDate1: new Date(year, month, day, 23, 59, 59),
  endDate2: new Date(year, month,day, 23, 59, 59),
  eventAlias: entry,
  addDate: new Date()
});
```

And here is what I get:

### [image]

It's probably due to TimeZone but I don't know how to solve it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore timestamp fields don't actually store timezones in them.  In fact, neither do JavaScript Date objects.  When you write a Timestamp field, you're always based in UTC.  According to the [API documentation for Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp):

> A Timestamp represents a point in time independent of any time zone or
>   calendar, represented as seconds and fractions of seconds at
>   nanosecond resolution in UTC Epoch time.

What you're seeing is the Firestore console rendering those dates using the timezone configured on your local computer.  If you ask someone across the globe to look at the same thing, they'll see the same point in time, but with a different timezone.

If you want to write a timestamp with a specific clock time in a specific timezone, you should use some date manipulation library, such as MomentJS, to make sure you have the right moment in time for the timezone you intend.